# Angular injects `false` instead of the service I requested

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, coffeescript

I have a controller defined like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller 'DetailController', ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, apiService) ->
    onStart = () ->
      getData()
      getOtherData()

    # a bunch of other functions defined here

    getData = ->
      apiService.get('/detail/' + $routeParams.id).then (result) ->
        $scope.data = result.data # really a little bit more involved :)

    onStart()
```

This works.

Now, I want to use some `otherService` to do an extra thing in the `getData()` function. Let's say that `otherService` is defined as

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory 'otherService', () ->
    doTheThing = -> console.log('did the thing!')

    {
      doTheThing
    }
```

(this works in other parts of the application).

To use this in my controller, I do this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller 'DetailController', ($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, apiService, otherService) ->
    onStart = () ->
      getData()
      getOtherData()

    # a bunch of other functions defined here

    getData = ->
      apiService.get('/detail/' + $routeParams.id).then (result) ->
        $scope.data = result.data # really a little bit more involved :)
        otherService.doTheThing()

    onStart()
```

i.e. add one argument `otherService` at the end of the argument list, and then use it.

This gives me a `TypeError` because `doTheThing` isn't defined. Debugging, I see that `otherService` contains the value `false` rather than the service I requested.

Why?

Comment: does compiled factory script show `return` and a valid object? Not sure how the object value would get assigned without you assigning it

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah, the service is compiled to something ending with `return { ... }` and all the things in the object definition are valid (and defined, and not `false`...).

Comment: Also, there are no circular dependencies - `otherService` only depends on `appConfig`, a `value` object with no dependencies, and `$q`.

Comment: am guessing this is coffee , might want to tag question with that. Or is it typeScript? I don't use either

Comment: @charlietfl, yeah done. But that's just syntax, anyway :)

Comment: but it would be what changes the argument

Answer (score 1):

I am not very into Coffeescript, but when i transpile your code using: Try Coffeescript(http://coffeescript.org/), I got:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('otherService', function() {
  var doTheThing;
  doTheThing = function() {
    return console.log('did the thing!');
  };
  return {
    doTheThing: doTheThing
  };
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('DetailController', function($rootScope, $scope, $routeParams, apiService, otherService) {
  var getData, onStart;
  onStart = function() {
    getData();
    return getOtherData();
  };
  getData = function() {
    return apiService.get('/detail/' + $routeParams.id).then(function(result) {
      $scope.data = result.data;
      return otherService.doTheThing();
    });
  };
  return onStart();
});
```

I am not sure with returning onStart - because Controller should be ordinary constructor, but never mind i tried to jsbin that and remove unmet dependencies with $q.when and it works.

http://jsbin.com/cubekojuwu/edit?js,console,output

Main thing about factory is that it should return object which should be placed into DI container and your code looks ok.
So I suppose your problem is somewhere when transpiling something we can't see here.

Can you provide full "not-working" jsbin? You can put transpiled code into it.